# search box with button in textbox

Tags: html, css

i want to create a textbox that have a button inside of it just like i see in some sites, usually there is a textbox and at the right hand corner a button with a hand lens image and when the button is clicked the form is submitted. I have tried using divs to create something similar but i dont seem to get it. How is it done with css or are there some jquery magic to it ?

Comment: also how do i make the value of the textbox to remain even on focus until input is added ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Using a wrapper

The technique you're referring to doesn't actually have the button inside the textbox normally, the border and background of the button and textbox simply blend in with a wrapper div. Here is a basic example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxt4z/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" />
    <button>GO</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
}

input,
button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
}
```

### Using `position:absolute`

An alternative method is to position the button absolutely and attach it to the right. A benefit of this is that you can more easily implement the focus/active border around the text box. You can get around the text under the button issue by giving `padding-right` to the text box.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JW7g7/)

[image]

```
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

input,
button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
}

button {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}

input {
    padding-right:30px; /* button padding */
}
```

Comment: I think that absolute positioning would be an option too, where the button is displayed on top of the input element, so when the input gets highlighted the button is in the area that is being highlighted.

Comment: There is a major flaw with absolute positioning though; text will appear under the button.

Comment: Yes indeed. You could restrict your input though to take a certain amount of characters (or just increase it's size by js).

Comment: Updated my answer with the other option and a work around for the text under button issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily how you would best do it. However, here is what you asked for. Check out this jsFiddle. Make button position:absolute;

http://jsfiddle.net/j8bbj/

```
<input type="text" />
<button>si</button>



input[type="text"]
{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}

button
{
    position:absolute;
    left:165px;
    top:10px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `<button>` inside a text box but it would not look nice. The search box would be right next to the text box that you would think it is inside the text box.
I used this HTML code:

```
<input type="search">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="mySearch">
```

And the CSS:

```
#mySearch {
margin-left: -4px; // I put margin-left -4px because the left border of the button will be in contact with the search box's right border. This will make it look like the button is right inside the input field but it's not.
border-width: 1px; // border-width: 1px; because the input's default border-width is 1px.
background-color: white; //White because the input's default background-color is white.
border-color: black; //Black because the input's default border-color is black.
```

As you can notice, the search button's border, background-color, border-width should match with the search field's default settings.

[Here is a JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/uaetssqw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS code make it possible:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Search</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

<body>
<br>
<div class="w3-container" style="position:relative">
  <form action="yoursearch.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" class='w3-input w3-border' name='sendmsg' id='sendmsg'  required placeholder="type search here">
  <button  class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border  w3-round-xlarge " style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:16px;" >Go</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]